Can't pass Terraform outputs via GITHUB_OUTPUT for next job
I'm trying to build a Terraform pipeline using a GitHub workflow. It's a workflow with multiple jobs. Some jobs will be passed data, via GitHub's recommended method of using $GITHUB_OUTPUT.
My code is not working as expected, please see below for more context:
jobs:
  iam:
    needs: [api-services]
    name: "TF: IAM Resources"
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    permissions:
      contents: 'read'
      id-token: 'write'
    outputs:
      tf-run-svc-account: ${{ steps.admin-service-account.outputs.service-account-email }}
    steps:
      
        ...
    
      - name: Terraform output service account
        id: output
        working-directory: ${{ env.terraform-directory }}/${{ env.TF_MODULE }}
        run: |
          data=$(terraform output -json service_account_email | jq -r '.')
          echo "service_account_email=$data" >> "$GITHUB_ENV"
        
      - name: Set output context
        id: admin-service-account
        working-directory: ${{ env.terraform-directory }}/${{ env.TF_MODULE }}
        run: |
          # Access the environment variable set in the previous step
          echo "Retrieved service account email: ${{ env.service_account_email }}"
          echo "service-account-email=${{ env.service_account_email }}" >> "$GITHUB_OUTPUT"

      
  storage:
    needs: [iam]
    permissions:
      contents: 'read'
      id-token: 'write'
    steps:
     # This step returns empty strings, as if nothing is getting passed.
      - name: Gather resource dependencies 
        run: |
          echo "gcp_service_account_run=\"${{ needs.iam.outputs.tf-run-svc-account }}\""
          echo "GCP Service Account: ${{ needs.iam.outputs.tf-run-svc-account }}"

The exact code above produces an empty string in the "Gather resource dependencies" step in storage job, meaning nothing is getting passed to my second step. However, when I hard code the value and replace the Terraform output, the code works fine:
      - name: Terraform output service account
        id: output
        working-directory: ${{ env.terraform-directory }}/${{ env.TF_MODULE }}
        run: |
          data="hard-coded-value" # <--- Hard coding this works and i see the value in the next step 
          echo "service_account_email=$data" >> "$GITHUB_ENV"

Anyone know why I see this behavior? I've spent hours trying to crack it and I'm ending up nowhere.
My terraform setup action is configured like so:
    - uses: hashicorp/setup-terraform@v3
      with:
        terraform_version: "1.9.3"
        terraform_wrapper: false


Does echo $data output the correct value after data=$(terraform output -json service_account_email | jq -r '.')?

Hi @Azeem, yes i see the expected string.

Apparently, it looks good. Did you try underscores instead of hyphens in the output param name?

Before you extract a single value run this command to make sure the value is set and terraform works as expected:
terraform output


Terraform is configured and working as expected, im able to echo the data and see the expected string, I loose visibility as soon as the next job tries to access the output context

I can conform that the workflow passes the value in data -> env -> output -> storage job. So, if env var data has value, it will be passed to storage job. You also said that you could see the value of $data after terraform. It simply follows that this value will be visible inside the storage job. By the way, the storage job in the question is missing a runner. Are there any other differences between the workflow that you ran and the workflow that you showed in the question? Perhaps there is a simple typo somewhere?
